# Is footer dosen't show up because of this grid?

Tags: html, css

For some unknown reason I tried to make a gallery using Grid but the footer doesn't show up on this page, I tried on other pages footer works just to find where I'm mistaken?

[image: my gallery]

my HTML and CSS codes:

```css
    *{
        margin: 0;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 ; 
         margin-left:  auto;
         margin-right:  auto;

    }
     /*/****************HEADER/****************/     
    header img.ab {
        width: 35%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
       
    }
    header ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #FFA07A;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;

    }

    header ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: center;

    }

    header ul li a {
     display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;

    }

    li a:hover {
      background-color: #1F1300;
    }
    .photographehead{
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    hr {
        height: 12px;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px  ;
      grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px 200px ;
      grid-gap: 2px;
      justify-content: center;
      z-index: -999;
    }
    div img.sadlife{
        float: left;
        width:  400px;
        height: 200px;
        object-fit: cover;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .grid-container > div {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 0;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .lightbox {
      display: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .lightbox:target {
      display: block;
    }

    .lightbox span {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
    footer.graphfooter{
        clear: both;
        position: relative;
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        background-color:#A2B29F ;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 25px;   
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Salah Eddine Laouina</title>
        
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylephotographe.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <img  class="ab"src="logo.png">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Accueil.html"> ACCUEIL</a></li>
                <li><a href="oeuvres.html"> OEUVRES</a></li>
                <li><a href="makingof.html"> MAKING OF</a></li>
                <li><a href="press-media.html"> PRESS AND MEDIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="photographie.html"> PHOTOGRAPHIE</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html"> CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
    </header>
    <div class="photographehead">
        <h2 style="margin-top: 10px;">BORN TO SHOOT THE WORLD AROUND ME</h2>
        <h6>Artist photographe Marocain</h6>
        <br>
    <hr>
    <p>"La photographie est un instant qui se reflechit pas, suspendue à une fraction de seconds qui laisse à réfléchir."</p>
    <address class="author">-Rémy Donnadieu</address>
    <br>
    <h3> SALAH EDDINE LAOUINA ARTISTE PHOTOFRAPHE MAROCAIN </h3>
    </div>
    <div  class="grid-container">
      <div><a href="#p1">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo1.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p1">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo1.jpg')"></span>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#p2">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo2.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p2">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo2.jpg')"></span>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#p3">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo3.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p3">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo3.jpg')"></span>
      </div>  
      <div><a href="#p4">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo4.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p4">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo4.jpg')"></span>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#p5">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo5.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p5">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo5.jpg')"></span>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#p6">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo6.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p6">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo6.jpg')"></span>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#p7">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo7.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p7">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo7.jpg')"></span>
      </div>  
      <div><a href="#p8">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo8.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p8">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo8.jpg')"></span>
      </div>  
      <div><a href="#p9">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo9.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p9">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo9.jpg')"></span>
      </div>  
      <div><a href="#p10">
        <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo10.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p10">
      <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo10.jpg')"></span>
      </div> 
      </div>
    <footer class="graphfooter" >
        <figure>
      <img src="biographie/salaheddinelaouina-1.png" alt="S.LAOUINA" style="width:15%">
      <figcaption><span>S.LAOUINA</span></figcaption>
            <p>SALAH EDDINE LAOUINA ARTISTE PEINTRE ET PHOTOGRAPHE MAROCAIN</p>
            <p>Copyright 2020 © LAOUINA</p>
      </div>
      </figure> 
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Voting to close as the issue are caused by missing closing tags. Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) the next time and check if you have a correct and valid markup first!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in some of your anchors ("<a>") in your HTML.

Some of them are not closed, like , for example:

```
<div>
 <a href="#p7">
  <img class="sadlife"  src="photographie/photo7.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="p7">
  <span style="background-image: url('photographie/photo7.jpg')"></span>
</div>
```

Look that the second anchor (id="p7") was left open (without close tag ). Leave tags unclosed can mess with all your document structure.

That problem was repeated in some tags of your HTML. Use a good code editor like VSCode to avoid that kind of error.

The link below is of a codepen with your HTML fixed. You can use a file compare tool like winmarge to see what I've changed.

https://codepen.io/niconeves/pen/ExXdRBG

Comment: Your link seems to be broken. Can u please edit it again. It is pasting `http://%20https//codepen.io/niconeves/pen/ExXdRBG` in the urlbar

Comment: Estrange, here its ok. Try acess directly in your address bar: https://codepen.io/niconeves/pen/ExXdRBG. Notice that image links are broken, but the layout is perfect,

Comment: that's much better, I appreciate you for taking time for my code.